# SVN how to export files from single commit?

Tags: svn

Is there any possibility to export files that had been changed or modified in single commit?

This would be usefull for deploying changes to web serwer after commiting them to repository (given that the server dont have svn to update from).

Comment: Absolutely. I use this every week.  Let me link to my question.

Comment: I didnt add that to question: I mean in console, not GUI interface.

Answer (score 1):

Console, Windows-unfriendly

`svn diff --summarize -r N-1:N` inside working copy produces a list (file per line with status indicator,spaces-separates) of affected in range files.

You have after only

- gawk to get $2
- pass result to xargs

In case of more one 1 revision in range one additional step added after gawk: sort -u

Answer (score 0):

commit your changes, when the window open, select the checked files and right click export to (destination)

Comment: This will export all files from the current revision. No only the changed ones from a specific revision.

Comment: Im mean how to do it in consle, not some GUI ;-)

Comment: @AliIssa As the poster wants a command in the console (see his comment on the question), your answer doesn't qualify. Besides, for a good answer, you would have to add more information. e.g. the tool you are talking about (I assume it's Tortoise.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a `diff` of changes between two revisions using `svn diff -r rev1:rev2`. [More information here.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re09.html) You can then apply the diff file to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Poster wants to export a change set. [Exporting Only changed files from subversion maintaining directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783362/exporting-only-changed-files-from-subversion-maintaining-directory-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Show the log info. Select two commits you want to compare/export by clicking Ctrl. Right-click choose 'Compare Revisions'. Then a dialogue named 'Files changed' will show up. You will see a list of files have changed between the commits. Select all files, then right click to export. :p