# What is the TFS equivalent of Tortoise SVN compare revisions / export selection to:

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn

I'm migrating over from Tortoise SVN to TFS/Visual studio which I'm pretty new to.
The most useful/often used feature within Tortoise SVN was the ability to select a revision, or several revisions of a site, and then exporting only those differences to another folder of my choice, and upload these to our server.

Basically I'd go to show log, click latest revision and then shift click how far I'd want to go back, right click and select 'Compare revisions'. This would get me a list of all files changed. Now I can select all these files, and click 'Export Selection To' and SVN would copy them to a folder for uploading.

In TFS I can see view history and get a list of changes, but theres no way of exporting just these changes to a folder.

We don't have FTP, or intending on opening FTP up, so I guess TFS must have either an equivalent or a different process entirely I've not yet found.

Cheers

Comment: Why you need to export the older changes and upload to your server in SVN?

Comment: You misunderstand - in SVN it exports the latest differences. So if you've changed 50 files across 10 different directories, instead of manually looking for the files, it does it automatically.

Comment: Seems you are talking bout  the feature like this: [Exporting Only changed files from subversion maintaining directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783362/exporting-only-changed-files-from-subversion-maintaining-directory-structure). It's not able to simply do this through VS IDE, settings in TFS. You have to achieve this through TFS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFS, that a **changeset** contains all the pending changes of one check in operation.  You could view and compare the changes in different revision, but it's **not** able to only export the changes in a changeset. There had also been a related uservoice: [Package and download changed files of a changeset](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3993787-package-and-download-changed-files-of-a-changeset)

If you want to get/work on an older version in history include **all** files for a branch or root project folder. Then you could  **Get Specific Version**  instead of get latest version of the branch in TFS. Details please refer this question: [TFS Get Specific Version into separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597476/tfs-get-specific-version-into-separate-folder) 
How to do this in VS: right click the branch-**Advance**-Get Specific Version.

---

Update

If you want to only get changed files like this in tortoisesvn :[Exporting Only changed files from subversion maintaining directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783362/exporting-only-changed-files-from-subversion-maintaining-directory-structure)

It's not able to simply do this through VS IDE, settings in TFS. You have to achieve this through TFS API.